# Importing PyTorch before using pandas.DataFrame.plot() causes Jupyter kernel to crash

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, pytorch

I'm running windows 10 with the following library versions:

```
matplotlib  3.3.3
torch       1.7.0
pandas      1.1.4
```

When I load from CSV a dataframe and plot its data BEFORE `import torch`, I get no issues. However, if I put all of my import statements at the top of the notebook, as is tradition, I instead get a crashed kernel with the following pop up message:

> *The kernel for anom_detect_nn.ipynb appears to have died. It will
> restart automatically.*

When I look at my shell, I see two error messages:

> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll
> already initialized.
>
> OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the
> OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous,
> since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best
> thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked
> into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP
> runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented
> workaround you can set the environment variable
> KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute,
> but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For
> more information, please see
> http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

It seems like other users on SO have experienced this before, but all of the solutions apply to MacOS users. I've tried them anyway:

1. `conda install nomkl`
2. `pip uninstall everything`, `pip install everything`
3. I did not use the dangerous workaround `KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE`

Thanks to the above steps entire set-up is now a tangled mess where I can't `pip install` anything successfully, and modules that are successfully installed can no longer be imported without `Module not found` errors.

This is a real pain, and I'm at my wits end. I'm currently uninstalling everything Python on my system and starting over. Not a happy camper. Any solutions that are for Windows and not Mac, should this problem persist when I start over?

Comment: I have this exact issue: matplotlib works, unless I `import torch`. If I `import torch`, calling `plt.subplots()` kills the kernel. Commenting out the import lets it work.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. This worked for me:

- put `plt` before `import torch`
- use `imshow` immediately
- `import torch`
- use `imshow` (and it doesn't crash)

I don't know why, but it works...